# GraphQL Mutation how to make fields optional to update fields only by selection and generate schema

Tags: graphql, graphql-schema

I have a graphql mutation defined as follows

```graphql
type Mutation {
    updateParts(
      partId: String!
      parts: PartRequest!
    ): UpdatePartsResponse!
}

input PartRequest {
    name: String!
    image: Strings!
    boltTypes: [Bolts]!
}

input Bolts {
    code: String!
    metadata: String!
}
```

Mhy requirement was to update fields upon selection as following.

- update all

```graphql
mutation {
  updateParts(
    partId: "0x1223"
    parts: {
      name: "some"
      image: "dark.png"
      boltTypes: [
        { code: "A", metadata: "B" }
      ]
    }
  ) 
  }
}
```

- Update by selection: name only

```graphql
mutation {
  updateParts(
    partId: "0x1223"
    parts: {
      name: "some"
    }
  ) 
  }
}
```

- Update by selection: parts only

```graphql
mutation {
  updateParts(
    partId: "0x1223"
    parts: {
      boltTypes: [
        { code: "A", metadata: "B" }
      ]
    }
  ) 
  }
}
```

How to construct a schema to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your arguments optional to achieve this. Try the following schema:

```graphql
type Mutation {
    updateParts(
        partId: String!
        parts: PartRequest!
    ): UpdatePartsResponse!
}

input PartRequest {
    name: String
    image: String
    boltTypes: [Bolts!]
}

input Bolts {
    code: String!
    metadata: String!
}
```

Notice the `PartRequest` input object. The fields are nullable. That means you don't necessarily need to provide a value for those arguments. The `!` means they are `NON_NULL` types, which means you have to provide a value for those always.

I have made the `boltTypes` field type to `[Bolts!]` which means the `boltTypes` field can be `null`, but the array cannot have `null` as an element.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, If you use the Netflix DGS framework, You can use **DgsDataFetchingEnvironment** to get selected properties in Input object as a **LinkedHashMap**.

```
@DgsMutation
public Customer updateParts(DgsDataFetchingEnvironment dfe, @InputArgument String partId, @InputArgument PartRequest parts) {
    LinkedHashMap inputData = dfe.getArgument("parts");
    return partsService.updatePartsPartially(inputData);
}
```

Here **PartRequest** objects contain all the fields meanwhile **LinkedHashMap** only contains fields that are defined in the query. Let's say in the query that you only update "*name*" then **PartRequest** object "*parts*" field is null. Then you can't explicitly define whether this field not updated by the query or not. Because null is also an acceptable value.

But if you get the argument from the **DgsDataFetchingEnvironment** class as **LinkedHashMap** it only contains "*name*" field.
So you can use it to dynamically update only those columns in the Database.